# When the increase linux terminal gui size using a mouse, ncurses window border afterimage problem arise

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, terminal, ncurses

I set a ncurses window size 26, 60, 1, 1.

w = newwin( 26, 60, 1, 1 );

Set borders.

```
box(w, 0, 0);
```

When the program is executed, if the linux terminal size smaller than ncurses window's size, and i try to increase the linux terminal size using the mouse, window's borders afterimage problem arise.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcvUM.png) this picture is try to increase the terminal size.

Please let me know if there seems to be a lack of explanation for the situation.

Comment: did you try use other app which uses ncurses, or did you try on different terminal? For me it looks like terminal problem not your application issue.

Comment: Without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there's no useful information.